# Import in body of module; reorder to top import/first

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Hello I am writing simple app in react and my index.js looks like this. I'm configuring redux store and redux-persistor and i get this error after importing all stuff I need. Does anyone know how to fix this? I have eslint extension installed in vscode and cannot disable it because some package depends on it.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

import './index.css';
import App from './App';

import { store, persistor } from './redux/store';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <App />
      </PersistGate>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: What is the error? What line?

Comment: Line 11:1:  Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.